# Odoo 10 - Extend view to include related model field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I am trying to extend the view which displays packages in Odoo 10 so it display also the product_id:

```
<record id="stock_view_picking_form_enhanced" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock_view_picking_form_enhanced</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="priority">20</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='pack_operation_product_ids']/tree/field[@name='package_id']" position="after">
            <field name="package_id.product_id"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

So basically I am looking to display related field `product_id` from `pack_operation_product_id`.

Which is the right approach to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must include the related field in your inherited python class.

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', related='package_id.product_id', string='Product', store=True)
```

Then in XML you can write like the following:

```
<record id="stock_view_picking_form_enhanced" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock_view_picking_form_enhanced</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="priority">20</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='pack_operation_product_ids']/tree/field[@name='package_id']" position="after">
            <field name="product_id"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```